# How to import coincide table of r.coin tool of QGIS in Excel

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, tabulate, cross-tabulation

I am trying to do a crosstabulation analysis with QGIS. I have used the grass tool r.coin and I have got the coincide report in txt format. However, I want to work with that report in excel, but I don´t know how to import it in excel in a way it keeps the original columns and differentiates between pages, etc.

You can see in the following link how the output table of the tool looks like:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.coin.html

Answer (score 0):

Two possible work flows:
You could just copy-paste the r.coin output into a text file, change the pipe characters '|' to commas, then import into excel as comma separated values. A bit fiddly, but it could work.

Maybe more relevant would be the `r.statistics` module? This will give you a new raster with statistics from a cover raster in each category of a base raster.